# Зачем функция mysqli_real_escape_string экранирует некоторые символы?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> Экранируемые символы NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", и Control-Z.

Источник: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

1. С одинарными и двойными кавычками `'` `"` понятно. Если их не экранировать они разломают SQL-запрос (собственно это и есть защита от любых SQL-инъекций, т.к. за пределы кавычек выйти не получится).
2. С обратным слешем `\` и `\n`, `\r` - тоже всё ясно, т.к. это управляющие последовательности в PHP ну и сам обратный слеш.
3. А зачем экранируется это: `NUL (ASCII 0)` и `Control-Z`?

Comment: В Linux терминале CTRL+Z остановка процесса. Возможно если не заэкранировать, то процесс остановится.

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко А нулевой байт означает конец строки в C.

Comment: По поводу NUL есть предположение, что используются нуль-терминальные строки, а это как известно, признак конца строки. Чтобы этого не было нужно экранировать

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко Ctrl+Z Это только в терминале остановка процесса. ничего конечно не остановится. Но на некоторых платформах он означает конец файла